# [Spring boot]return wrong value date in json response

Tags: java

I'm trying build rest api with spring boot. and got stuck:

> Value in mysql: 2018-06-13 10:45:17 (datetime)
>
> When I got it by java: Wed Jun 13 10:45:17 ICT 2018
>
> But json return(format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss): 2018-06-13 03:45:17

why HH:mm:ss is 03:45:17, it must 10:45:17 ?

my code getter function:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
}
```

Can you help me in this case?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Check for time zone disparity. It's jus a getter and it returns the value which it was set to

Comment: `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", locale = "en_GB")`  replace with locale for ICT

Comment: ICT is UTC+7, so clearly the value you are seeing in the JSON is UTC.  As long as the user of the JSON knows this, there is no problem, they both represent the same instant in time.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JimGarrison, I'm using Postman, anyway to change UTC to ICT ???