# Spring Boot Wrong date returned

Tags: java, spring, date

I have an entity Person

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Person {

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Calendar dob;
}
```

And some dao classes

```
@Data
public class PersonResponse {

  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Calendar dob;
}
```

```
@Data
public class PersonRequest{
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Calendar dob;
}
```

When storing values it works perfectly. Example if I send "2000-01-01" it's stored as is in the database "2000-01-01". But When I try to return it I get "1999-12-31".

Now it's clear that is a ***Timezone Problem*** but I don't know how to fix it.

###### My explanation for the cause

The user timezone is GMT+1 so it is some how retrieved as "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000 +01:00", then parsed to UTC "1999-12-31T23:00:00.000 +00:00" to finally be returned as "1999-12-31".

But why? And how can I prevent this knowing that users timezones can change (so adding the time offset manually of 1 hour won't work).

I tried also changing type from Calendar to java.util.Date and java.sql.Date... but no result.

Similar questions where asked before like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829014/spring-bootreturn-wrong-value-date-in-json-response) but I still couldn't understand how to fix it

Comment: Can you avoid using the cumbersome and long outdated `Calendar` class? `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are not (much) better. At least if using at least version 5.0 of Hibernate, you can use `LocalDate`. It’s independent of time zone so should eliminate your problem.

Comment: Which database engine and which data type in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Applicable try to switch from class `Calendar` to `LocalDate`. `LocalDate` does not take time zone into consideration. This should resolve your issue (and simplify your code). Also, for formatting the `LocalDate` with Json see the answer to this question: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)